# Создание проекта в Android Studio

Tags: проект, android

Когда создаю новый проект с пустым активити, то при загрузке проекта не создается ни активити, ни java-, ни xml-файлов.

В чем причина и как ее можно исправить?

Comment: Вы в диалоге выбора шаблона, наверное, выбрали Add no activity (вроде так называется)

Comment: благодарю) Точно)))))